# How to migrate from form-data to Raw JSON in Kotlin?

Tags: android, api, kotlin, mvvm, dagger-hilt

Description:
I was previously using multipart/form-data in my Android app, but I need to migrate to Raw JSON format. I encountered a 422 error in the response from the server, indicating that nothing is being uploaded. Previously, when the API was still using form-data, everything worked fine.

Here are the relevant details and code snippets:

Chucker API Screenshot: [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyoac.png)

My Request Screenshot: [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtD8G.png)

My Response Screenshot: [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KipKU.png)

API from Postman Screenshot: [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHg7p.png)

**Data Class:**
This is my data class:

```kotlin
data class ResponseUpdateUser(
    @SerializedName("address")
    val address: String,
    @SerializedName("city")
    val city: String,
    @SerializedName("created_at")
    val createdAt: String,
    @SerializedName("email")
    val email: String,
    @SerializedName("id")
    val id: Int,
    @SerializedName("image")
    val image: String,
    @SerializedName("isAdmin")
    val isAdmin: Int,
    @SerializedName("name")
    val name: String,
    @SerializedName("phone")
    val phone: String,
    @SerializedName("updated_at")
    val updatedAt: String
)
```

**API Service:**
This is my API service:

```kotlin
@Multipart
@PUT("user/update")
suspend fun updateDataUser(
    @Query("token") token: String,
    @Part file: MultipartBody.Part? = null,
    @Part("name") name: RequestBody?,
    @Part("phone") phoneNumber: RequestBody?,
    @Part("address") address: RequestBody?,
    @Part("city") city: RequestBody?,
    @Part("email") email: RequestBody? = null
): ResponseUpdateUser
```

**ViewModel:**
This is my ViewModel:

```kotlin
@HiltViewModel
class EditAkunViewModel @Inject constructor(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    fun updateDataUser(
        token: String,
        file: File?,
        name: String,
        phoneNumber: String,
        address: String,
        city: String
    ) {
        val requestFile = file?.let {
            reduceFileImage(it).asRequestBody("image/jpg".toMediaTypeOrNull())
        }
        val image = requestFile?.let {
            MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", file.name, it)
        }
        val namaRequestBody = name.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val kotaRequestBody = city.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val alamatRequestBody = address.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        val noHpRequestBody = phoneNumber.toRequestBody("text/plain".toMediaType())
        viewModelScope.launch {
            repository.updateDataUser(
                token,
                image,
                namaRequestBody,
                noHpRequestBody,
                alamatRequestBody,
                kotaRequestBody
            )
        }
    }
}
```

**Fragment:**
This is my Fragment:

```kotlin
@AndroidEntryPoint
class EditAkunFragment : Fragment() {
    private var _binding: FragmentEditAkunBinding? = null
    private val binding get() = _binding!!
    private val viewModel: EditAkunViewModel by viewModels()
    private var uri: String = ""
    private var fileImage: File? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {

        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View {
        _binding = FragmentEditAkunBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false)
        return binding.root
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        val progressDialog = ProgressDialog(requireContext())
        progressDialog.setMessage("Please Wait...")
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false)
        val bundle = arguments
        binding.apply {
            etNama.setText(checkNull(bundle?.getString(USER_NAME).toString()))
            etKota.setText(checkNull(bundle?.getString(USER_CITY).toString()))
            etAlamat.setText(checkNull(bundle?.getString(USER_ADDRESS).toString()))
            etNoHp.setText(checkNull(bundle?.getString(USER_PHONE_NUMBER).toString()))

            Glide.with(requireContext())
                .load(bundle?.getString(USER_IMAGE) ?: R.drawable.default_image)
                .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(8))
                .into(ivProfile)
        }
        binding.btnBack.setOnClickListener {
            findNavController().popBackStack()
        }
        binding.ivProfile.setOnClickListener {
            openImagePicker()
        }
        binding.btnSimpan.setOnClickListener {
            Log.d("cek path", fileImage?.path ?: "gada")
            resetErrors()
            val nama = binding.etNama.text.toString()
            val kota = binding.etKota.text.toString()
            val alamat = binding.etAlamat.text.toString()
            val noHp = binding.etNoHp.text.toString()

            val isValid = validation(nama, kota, alamat, noHp)
            if (isValid) {
                val token = bundle?.getString(USER_TOKEN)
                if (token != null) {
                    viewModel.updateDataUser(token, fileImage, nama, noHp, alamat, kota)
                    progressDialog.show()
                    Handler().postDelayed({
                        progressDialog.dismiss()
                        findNavController().popBackStack()
                        Toast.makeText(
                            requireContext(),
                            "Berhasil Update Data!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }, 1500)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun resetErrors() {
        binding.apply {
            namaContainer.error = ""
            kotaContainer.error = ""
            alamatContainer.error = ""
            noHpContainer.error = ""
        }
    }

    private fun checkNull(value: String?): String {
        return when {
            value.isNullOrEmpty() -> ""
            value == "null" -> ""
            else -> value
        }
    }

    private fun validation(
        nama: String,
        kota: String,
        alamat: String,
        nohp: String
    ): Boolean {
        return when {
            nama.isEmpty() -> {
                binding.namaContainer.error = "Nama tidak boleh kosong!"
                false
            }
            kota.isEmpty() -> {
                binding.kotaContainer.error = "Kota tidak boleh kosong!"
                false
            }
            alamat.isEmpty() -> {
                binding.alamatContainer.error = "Alamat tidak boleh kosong!"
                false
            }
            nohp.isEmpty() -> {
                binding.noHpContainer.error = "Nomor Hp tidak boleh kosong!"
                false
            }
            nohp.length < 11 -> {
                binding.noHpContainer.error = "Minimum Nomor 11 digit!"
                false
            }
            else -> true
        }
    }

    private val startForProfileImageResult =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result: ActivityResult ->
            val resultCode = result.resultCode
            val data = result.data
            when (resultCode) {
                Activity.RESULT_OK -> {
                    val fileUri = data?.data
                    uri = fileUri.toString()
                    if (fileUri != null) {
                        fileImage = uriToFile(fileUri, requireContext())
                        loadImage(fileUri)
                    }
                }
                ImagePicker.RESULT_ERROR -> {
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), ImagePicker.getError(data), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
                else -> {
                    // Handle other result codes if needed
                }
            }
        }

    private fun loadImage(uri: Uri) {
        binding.apply {
            Glide.with(binding.root)
                .load(uri)
                .transform(CenterCrop(), RoundedCorners(12))
                .into(ivProfile)
        }
    }

    private fun openImagePicker() {
        ImagePicker.with(this)
            .crop()
            .saveDir(File(requireContext().externalCacheDir, "ImagePicker"))
            .compress(1024)
            .maxResultSize(1080, 1080)
            .createIntent { intent ->
                startForProfileImageResult.launch(intent)
            }
    }
}
```

I'm using MVVM and DI with Dagger Hilt. I hope someone can help me with this migration.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!